# How to install openvpn client on 64 bit raspian?

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit

I tried to install openvpn client, I have a pi 5 with raspberry pi OS 64-bit

I ran the apt updates and then ran
`sudo apt install openvpn -y`

and got an error:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
> state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
> may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  openvpn : Depends:
> libpkcs11-helper1 (>= 1.28) but it is not installable
> Recommends: easy-rsa but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am assuming that these packages don't work for the 64-bit version of the OS, how do I get the packages and install them?

If its not that then what is it?

Comment: `you have held broken packages` what packages have you *held*?? `I am assuming` wrong

Comment: alternatively, have you done an `apt update` first?

Comment: Yeah, didn't help

Comment: The `openvpn` install worked perfectly on my RPi 5. You might have a broken package system??? You could try [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=debian+how+to+repair+APT&t=newext&atb=v369-1&ia=web) to find some tools and advice on repairing it. Otherwise, I'd suggest a re-install (you have backups?).

Comment: @Seamus do you have a 64 bit os?

Comment: `$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi5 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.63-1+rpt1 (2023-11-24) aarch64 GNU/Linux`.  yes

Comment: I have same version: Linux pi5 6.1.0-rpi7-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.63-1+rpt1 (2023-11-24) aarch64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out apt was messed up on install. I installed from raspberri pi installer and selected 64-bit os. I tried reinstalling apt and that did not work. I eneded up reinstalling the whole OS and downloading from this site: https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/ and then using the custom OS option and selecting the .xz image.